# material-ui card with openlayers map inside?

Tags: reactjs, openlayers, material-ui

I'm trying to place an openlayers map inside a material-ui card component.  I've tried placing a div containing the map inside the card text and the card media sections.

Can anyone help me figure out the correct way to put a map inside the card?

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import 'openlayers/dist/ol.css';
import ol from 'openlayers';   
import {Card, CardActions, CardHeader, CardMedia} from 'material-ui/Card';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';    
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper'    
import baseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/lightBaseTheme'
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme'
import '../components/tap_events'
import styles from '../styles/ExportInfo.css'
import {updateExportInfo} from '../actions/exportsActions.js';    

class ExportInfo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)



    getChildContext() {
        return {muiTheme: getMuiTheme(baseTheme)};
    }
    componentDidMount() {

        this._initializeOpenLayers()
    }
    _initializeOpenLayers() {

        const scaleStyle = {
            background: 'white',
        };


        this._map = new ol.Map({
            controls: [
                new ol.control.ScaleLine(),
                new ol.control.Attribution({
                    collapsible: false,
                    collapsed: false,
                }),
                new ol.control.Zoom({
                    className: styles.olZoom
                })
            ],
            interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
                keyboard: false,
                altShiftDragRotate: false,
                pinchRotate: false
            }),
            layers: [
                // Order matters here
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                }),
            ],
            target: 'infoMap',
            view: new ol.View({
                projection: "EPSG:3857",
                center: [110, 0],
                zoom: 2.5,
                minZoom: 2.5,
                maxZoom: 22,
            })
        });
    }
    render() {
        const providers = this.props.providers;
        console.log("this is it"+providers[0])
        return (
            <div className={styles.wholeDiv}>
            <div className={styles.root}>    
                    <Paper className={styles.paper} zDepth={2} rounded>
                        <div className={styles.mapCard}>
                            <Card >
                                <CardHeader
                                    title="Selected Area of Interest"
                                    actAsExpander={true}
                                    showExpandableButton={true}
                                />

                                <CardMedia expandable={true}>
                                    <div id="infoMap" className={styles.map} ref="olmap">

                                    </div>

                                </CardMedia>
                            </Card>
                        </div>
                    </Paper>                   
            </div>
            </div>


        )
    }
}



ExportInfo.childContextTypes = {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}



export default (ExportInfo)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id of your div (summaryMap) doesn't match target field in olmap configuration ('infoMap') both of them should be the same.

Additionally instead of calling _initializeOpenLayers in componentDidMount. I would recommend using ref callback and initialize target with actual control instead of string.

```
<div id="summaryMap" className={styles.map} ref={olmapDiv => this. _initializeOpenLayers(olmapDiv)}>

</div>
```

Comment: I accidentally copied from one of my other map pages.  But, that did not fix it either!  :(  I tried putting the map into children={} of the cardMedia and still nothing!  I'm at a loss.

Comment: Your second suggestion is what did it!  Thank you so much @baalazamon!

Comment: One more question for you @baalazamon  Everytime state changes, the render() method is called, which in turn adds multiple maps to the div with the way you've mentioned above.  Do you know any way around that?

Comment: Add a key property to dig, keep reference to div in your class and return from initialize method if it's already set

Comment: Weird, but effective ... it works great for React 16.xx ... I wanted tu use useState hooks with no good results- Thanks @baalazamon